# Node + Express router + Type Script : string arg is not assignable to requesthandlerparams type

Tags: node.js, typescript, express

I'm following a tuto to create a full rest api, then, i create a TS class that export a new express router :

```
import { Router, Request, Response, NextFunction } from 'express';


export class TourRouter {
public router: Router;

constructor() {
    this.router = Router();

    this.init();
}

public init(): void {
    this.router.get(
        '/',
        this.getTours
    );
}

private getTours(request: Request, response: Response, next: NextFunction) {
    // Some JSON
    const tours = {
        "now": "2018-09-09 18:40:00",
        "date": "2018-09-09",
        "tours": [
            {
                "time": "8",
                "places": 8,
                "isPast": false
            },
            {
                "time": "11",
                "places": 8,
                "isPast": false
            },
            {
                "time": "14",
                "places": 8,
                "isPast": false
            },
            {
                "time": "17",
                "places": 8,
                "isPast": false
            }             
        ]
    };

    response.send(tours);
}
}

const tourRoutes = new TourRouter();
tourRoutes.init();

export default tourRoutes.router;
```

When i want to use this new Router in my App.ts as follow, i'm getting a TS error and the build failed with the message :

```
Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'RequestHandlerParams'
```

The use statement is :

```
    private _routes(): void {
    let router = express.Router();

    router.get('/', (request, response, next) => {
        response.json({
            message: 'Hello World'
        });
    });

    this.express.use('/', router);
    this.express.use('/api/v1/tours', TourRouter);
}
```

As if TourRouter, in my case was not a Router as i expect but something else, but don't know why. What i'm missing ?

Regards

Comment: How did you import `TourRouter` in App.ts? Can you share the import statement??

Comment: The simpliest way in App.ts :
import { TourRouter } from './routes/TourRouter';

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you are importing the `TourRouter` class instead of the actual router, which is the default export.  Replace `import { TourRouter } from './routes/TourRouter';` with `import TourRouter from './routes/TourRouter';`.  You might want to import the router using a name other than `TourRouter` to avoid confusion.

TypeScript knows that the arguments you are passing to `this.express.use` do not match any of the valid overload signatures, but it doesn't know which overload signature you intended to use.  It (incorrectly) guesses the `(...handlers: RequestHandlerParams[]) => T` signature, which explains the strange error that the string path is not assignable to `RequestHandlerParams`.

Comment: It's all right... I would say that when i follow a tuto... i had to put my glasses on my eyes, to avoid my and your time waste lol

Answer (score 0):

For me it's perhaps a strange problem with the "Request" "Response"  "NextFunction" type. 
Can you try to simply  **import * from express** and qualify each type with  express. ?

Request --> express.Request

https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/16639

Comment: btw, be carefull it's look like you call  the method "init()" from your TourRouter twice, first time in the constructor, then at the creation

Comment: So, replace import statement with the one you mentioned, but.. nothing changes... Maybe a wrong version of express, after updating express got another ts error : An interface may only extend a class or another interface (index.d.ts from @types/express)